# R -- Plotrix Package, gap.boxplot function: Display Box Plot with Broken Axis/Gap

Tags: r, boxplot

I am a new R user and have limited experience coding, so I am guessing my problem in easily solved.  I have downloaded the plotrix package in order to use the function "gap.boxplot" within R.  I am trying to create a broken axis for a boxplot with one outlying data point.

I have uploaded my data via .xls through the read.xls function in the pkg::gdata package.  My code so far looks like this:

```
boxplot(MaiBelaData$AlT ~ MaiBelaData$Site, xlab="Mai Bela Catchment (site)", 
        ylab="Dissolved Aluminum (mg/L)", col=terrain.colors(8), 
        par(cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=1,cex.main=1.2))
```

The summary of my data is:

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's

0.0010  0.0130  0.0450  0.6745  0.2860 28.0000       8

Where "MaiBelaData$AlT" contains my concentration data and "MaiBelaData$Site" specifies my site.

I got a similar piece of code to work with a simple example:

```
gap.boxplot(MaiBelaData$AlT ~ MaiBelaData$Site, gap=list(top=c(25,15), bottom=c(NA,NA)))
```

But, when I run it with my data, i get this error:

Error in gap.boxplot(MaiBelaData$AlT ~ MaiBelaData$Site, xlab = "Mai Bela Catchment (site)",  : 
  gap cannot include the median, interquartiles or the staples

Comment: I have no idea what you problem is, but it does seem passing strange that you would use `read.xls` to import a csv file. Furthermore `read.xls` is in pkg::gdata.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I used the read.xls to upload an .xls file and yes, you are correct, from the pckg:gdata.  Clearly, I am still getting used to the terminology :/

Comment: You should at a minimum offer results of `summary(MaiBelData)`.

Comment: Sorry, I will make it more simple.  say i create a simple boxplot, boxplot(1:10,30).  I now want to remove 15 to 25 on the x-axis .. I create gap.boxplot(1:10,30, gap=list(top=c(25,15),bottom=c(NA,NA))) and it removes 15 to 25! Oh! I guess i just solved what I was stuck on.  So, my only remaining question is: how to I get the labels back onto new seperated axis?

Comment: So, now I know that code works ... I have applied it to my data, which has summary statistics now inserted above, with error message as shown above.  I don't understand because the removed data region is not within the meidan, or intequartiles.  To be honest, I am not sure what is being referrted to as "staples".

Comment: Staples are the whisker end caps.

Comment: You should write up an answer to your problem. Ideally it would include description of the data and how you resolved your confusion about 'top' and 'bottom' parameter specifications.

Comment: DWin -- thanks for walking me through my first post here.  Unfortunately, I can not post an answer because I still can't solve my problem.  I have found code that works to solve a simplified version of problem, but it doesn't work with my data for a reason unknown to me.